# How to change class of textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my textbox has a `class='cssText'`. I want to change this class to `'blck'` at runtime.

How can I access the class attribute of textbox and change its value using jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: $("#txt").attr("class") = 'blck'

Comment: ?? Anyways question was answered

Comment: I'm curious why your class name is called "cssText"? because IE uses this name to set/get the style information on an element.  e.g. alert(someObj.style.cssText) returns a value that reflects the value of the style="..." attribute on the object.

Comment: e.g. it isn't a reserved word, but the name raised my eyebrows when I read it... as "potentially an issue"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input#id").removeClass("cssText").addClass("blck");
```

or

```
$("input#id").attr("class", "blck");
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoudl select the textbox and then set the new class:

```
$(selector_for_textbox).removeClass('cssText').addClass('blck');
```

A possible selector for your textbox could ofcourse be the class, or otherwise an id or something:

```
$('#textbox'). //etc
$('input.cssText:text'). //etc
```

**Edit from comments**
You should use:

```
$('#txt').removeClass('cssText').addClass('blck');
```

Comment: can I change any attribute of the textbox like this? - For eg: I have a size attribute and I now want to change its value

Comment: You should then use attr(attrName, value); or for css properties: css(property, value); ie: $().css('height', '100px');